# Source code coverage indication for PHP application at specific intervals

Tags: php, profiling, code-coverage, real-time

I am fuzzing a PHP web application for vulnerabilities and I want to the source code coverage over a period of time (at certain time intervals) for a certain part of the programme (specific PHP files). For example, after 10 seconds 5% of that source code is touched, after 20 seconds 6%, etc. I have looked into PHPUnit and XDEBUG. I was able to generate a report with PHPUnit, but this only gives me information about how much source code was touched at the end. Does anyone know a tool that can give me periodically information on source code coverage of a PHP application or how to use XDEBUG to extract this kind of information?

Comment: Not sure what you expect to get from this?  If you are testing code(for example unit testing) then the important thing is the end result, not after the first couple of tests.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am fuzzing a PHP application to find vulnerabilities. Source code coverage is an indication of how good my developed fuzzer works. I want to analyse the interval information so I can see after how long no new lines of code are touched. There is for example an OWASP project that does this for Java/.NET (http://code-pulse.com/).